# React - UseState, UseRef..In Trouble

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

Can someone tell me whats wrong ?

I have a react function component where in I use 'useState' & 'UseRef' on a state variable like so..

```
    **A**. `const [nodeslist,_setNodeslist] = useState([]);`
    
    **B**. `const  nodeslistRef = useRef(nodeslist);`
    
    **C**.`const setNodeslist = (data)=>{
                nodeslistRef.current = data;
                _setNodeslist(data)
      }`
    
    **D**. somewhere ..on an event which adds nodes...

       `
       let n = {id:'someid',attrs:{name:'somename',descr:'somedescr'}};
       setNodeslist(prev=>[...prev,n]);
       `

    **E**. in another event handler...click.. I am trtying to find the node clicked..but I cant 
           iterate the 'nodeslist' with ref like so.. 

           `nodeslistRef.current.forEach((item,i)=>{
               .....
           });`

           ***GIVES ERROR nodeslistRef.current.forEach is NOT A FUNCTION..***

          a. `console.log(nodeslistRef.current)` shows -> prev=>[...prev,n] but not the DATA..
          b. `JSON.stringify(nodeslist)` on page shows expected data..and seems to updating as soon as 
             a node is added to the page..
```

SO WHATS WRONG ? Can someone help me ? just cant seem to get my head wrapped around it...

***As an aside, I am using EXACTLY the same schematics with another state variable and it all works as expected...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong with this. `setNodeslist(prev=>[...prev,n]);` Since you did this.
In here you will get data as function `prev=>[...prev, n]` not `[...prev, n]`

```
const setNodeslist = (data)=>{
  nodeslistRef.current = data;
  _setNodeslist(data)
}
```

That's why you get error like following:

```
prev=>[...prev,n] but not the DATA..
```

To fix this: try this.

```
const setNodeslist = (callback)=>{
  const newCallback = (prev) => {
    nodeslistRef.current = callback(prev);
    return nodesListRef.current;
  }
  _setNodeslist(newCallback)
}
```

Comment: This works...however, how do you explain the same schematics correctly doign everything as expected on another state variable ?? @Zhang TianYu

Comment: I guess it's not exactly the same. And this is the correct way to handle issue